# SQL Error code : Failed to open the referenced table " product"?

Tags: mysql

im newbee at SQL,i had a error when i create a foreign key (orderdetails) that references (products) table

```
   drop database My_Classicmodels ;
create database My_Classicmodels ;
use My_Classicmodels;

// creat table orders
create table orders (
 orderNumber INT(11) auto_increment primary key  ,
 orderDate datetime not null , 
 requiredDate datetime not null , 
 shippedDate datetime ,
 statuss varchar(15) not null , 
 comments text , 
 customerNumber int(11) not null 


) Engine = InnoDb ;

// creat  table productlines
create table productlines (
productLine Varchar(50) primary key , 
textDescription varchar(4000) ,
htmlDescription mediumtext ,
image mediumblob 
) ENgine =InnoDB ; 

// creat tabale orderdetails
create table orderdetails (
orderNumber Int(11) not null   ,
productCode varchar(15) not null , 
quantityOrdered Int(11)  not null ,
priceEach Double not null , 
orderLineNumber smallint(6) not null  ,

constraint  fk_order_number foreign key (orderNumber) references
orders ( orderNumber) on delete restrict on update cascade ,

constraint fk_productCode foreign key  ( productCode) references
products (productCode) ,
constraint fk_key primary key( orderNumber, productCode )




) Engine = InnoDb ; 

create table products ( 
productCode varchar(15) primary key ,
productName varchar(70) not null ,
productLine Varchar(50) not null,
productScale varchar(10) not null,
productVendor varchar(50) not null,
productDescription text not null , 
quantityInStock smallint not null , 
buyPrice double not null  ,
constraint fk_productLine foreign key (productLine) references 
productlines ( productLine) on delete restrict on update cascade 
 ) engine = InnoDB ; 


describe orderdetails ;
```

Comment: Some observations: 1. There's no good reason for a surrogate primary key to be anything other than an autoincrementing integer. 2. Money is rarely DOUBLE. It's why DECIMAL was invented.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Due your table's creation order  in you code you are referring to a table products that is not yet created

try change creation order this way 
You are referring to a t

```
create table products ( 
productCode varchar(15) primary key ,
productName varchar(70) not null ,
productLine Varchar(50) not null,
productScale varchar(10) not null,
productVendor varchar(50) not null,
productDescription text not null , 
quantityInStock smallint not null , 
buyPrice double not null  ,
constraint fk_productLine foreign key (productLine) references 
productlines ( productLine) on delete restrict on update cascade 
 ) engine = InnoDB ; 


// creat tabale orderdetails
create table orderdetails (
orderNumber Int(11) not null   ,
productCode varchar(15) not null , 
quantityOrdered Int(11)  not null ,
priceEach Double not null , 
orderLineNumber smallint(6) not null  ,

constraint  fk_order_number foreign key (orderNumber) references
orders ( orderNumber) on delete restrict on update cascade ,

constraint fk_productCode foreign key  ( productCode) references
products (productCode) ,
constraint fk_key primary key( orderNumber, productCode )
```